# python (baseball game) TypeError : not all arguments converted during string formatting

Tags: python, typeerror

```
    import random

    q=[0,0,0,0]

    p=random.randint(1000,9999)

    def div_1(x):
        A = [0,0,0,0]
        A[0]= (x-(x%1000))/1000
        A[1]= (x-(x%100))/100 -10*A[0]
        A[2]= (x-(x%10))/10 -100*A[0] - 10*A[1]
        A[3]= x -1000*A[0] - 100*A[1] - 10*A[2]
        return A

ranq = div_1(p)
m=1

while 1:
    n=input("Enter number: ")
    q = div_1(n)
    S=0
    B=0
    O=0
    i=0
    j=0
    for i in range(0, 3):
        for j in range(0, 3):
            if(ranq[i]==q[j]):
                if(i==j):
                    S+=1
                else:
                    B+=1
            j+=1
        i+=1

    print("Strike: {0}  Ball: {1}  Try: {2} \n".format(S, B, m))
    m+=1

    if S==4:
        print("Bingo!")
        break
    if(m<10):
        print("Error!")
        break
    else:
        continue
```

Can u guys solve this error?

the script keeps giving me TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting...

this code is written in python version 3.6

================================================================================

Comment: Full trace or line number would help

Comment: You're passing strings to `div_1`.

Comment: @user2357112   Then how should i change mt code?

Comment: See the duplicates.

Answer (score -1):

Since S,B, and m are integers, you want to put the correct formatting parameters like so:

```
'{:d}'.format(S)
```

Or in your case,

```
print("Strike: {:d}  Ball: {:d}  Try: {:d} \n".format(S, B, m))
```

The :d is telling the format method that you want to convert an integer to a string. And since you put the numbers in order anyway, there's no need for the 0,1, and 2 you put into the brackets.

Happy Coding!

Comment: That isn't actually necessary.

Comment: Still doesn't work ;;